# Dataweave 2 - String to DateTime could not be parsed

Tags: datetime, mule, dataweave

In my payload I am getting a simple text as the following sample:

`{date: "20191213294831"}`

I am trying to transform that to string date like this `"2019-12-13"`.
This is the code I am using:

```
newDate: (payload.date as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Cannot coerce String (20191213294831) to LocalDateTime, caused by:
>   Text '20191213294831' could not be parsed at index 0

I've tried with some types also DateTime but without a successful result.

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 4):

Your hours seems to be off, I see `29` make sure it's a valid number.

This works for me, provided I change the hours to something reasonable:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var data = {date: "20191213224831"}
---

data.date 
    as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyyMMddHHmmss"} 
    as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The format for parsing the input is not correct. `payload.date as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}` assumes the string is formatted with '-' and ':' and a space between day and time. For your input the correct format seems to be "yyyyMMddHHmmss", however as @George mentioned in his answer the value for the hours (29) is not valid and will cause the error `Cannot coerce String (20191213294831) to LocalDateTime, caused by: Text '20191213294831' could not be parsed: Invalid value for HourOfDay (valid values 0 - 23): 29`. You need to pass a valid date time.